# The size of closure (lambda function) not same as std::function or pointer

Tags: c++, c++14

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

std::function<int(int)> makeLambda1(int x) {
  return [x] (int y) { return x * y; };
}

auto makeLambda2(int x) {
  return [x] (int y) { return x * y; };
}

auto makeLambda3() {
  return [] (int y) { return 10 * y; };
}

int main() {
  auto lambda1 = makeLambda1(10);
  auto lambda2 = makeLambda2(10);
  auto lambda3 = makeLambda3();
  std::cout << sizeof(lambda1) << " ";
  std::cout << sizeof(lambda2) << " ";
  std::cout << sizeof(lambda3) << " ";
  std::cout << sizeof(int(*)(int)) << std::endl;
}
```

Output (https://ideone.com/ghoksF):

```
32 4 1 8
```

1. Why is the size of a capturing lambda 4 bytes and less than the size of the std::function (32 bytes)?
2. Why is the size of the not capturing lambda 1 byte and less than the size of a pointer to a function (8 bytes)?

Comment: g++ gives the same output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lambdas are just syntactic sugar for objects with an overloaded `operator()`.  That means that

```cpp
return [x] (int y) { return x * y; };
```

is equivalent to

```cpp
class unique_unnamed_type
{
private:
    const int x;
public:
    unique_unnamed_type(int x) : x{x} {}
    auto operator()(int y) { return x * y; } const
};
return unique_unnamed_type{x};
```

Just from looking, you can probably guess that `sizeof(unique_unnamed_type)` should equal `sizeof(int)`, since its only member is a single `int`.

---

In the non-capturing case, the equivalent object is only slightly different.

```cpp
return [] (int y) { return 10 * y; };
```

is equivalent to

```cpp
class unique_unnamed_type
{
private:
    using fp = int(*)(int);
    static auto unnamed_static_function(int y) { return 10 * y; }
public:
    auto operator()(int y) { return unnamed_static_function(y); } const
    operator fp() { return unnamed_static_function; } const
};
return unique_unnamed_type{};
```

This type's size will generally be `1`, like any class type with no members (objects need to have a unique address, so even "empty" objects take up one byte of storage, barring things like empty base optimization).

Notably it is smaller than a function pointer because it *isn't* a function pointer.  It's just a class with an implicit conversion operator that returns a pointer to a static member function.

---

`std::function` is a totally different beast.  It's a type-erased container for *any* callable type that has a compatible signature.  This type-erasure has some overhead, so `std::function` will generally be larger than a raw function pointer or a lambda, though it could be smaller, if the lambda captures a large object.  The actual callable that a `std::function` object refers to will be allocated dynamically, and so `sizeof(std::function<int(int)>)` doesn't include the size of the actual callable object.

Comment: As I known, captured variables by values are const by default. Thus, the private member of the first class unique_unnamed_type must be `const int x;`. Or the operator ()(int y) must be const unless `mutable` is specified to lambda.

Comment: @S.M. Edited to add const-qualification.  There are some other details like deleted assignment operators that I glossed over as well.  Just trying to keep it to what's relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1):

[1] `std::cout << sizeof(lambda1) << " ";`

this prints the size of `std::function`, which is implementation defined.

[2] `std::cout << sizeof(lambda2) << " ";`

this prints the size of unnamed unique class type instance, which has only one data member - `int`. The size of such closure is 4 - `sizeof(int)`.

[3] `std::cout << sizeof(lambda3) << " ";`

this prints the size of unnamed unique class type instance, which has no data members. The size of empty class cannot be empty, and it is just 1 byte. See [EBO](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ebo), *The size of any object or member subobject (unless [[no_unique_address]] -- see below) (since C++20) is required to be at least 1 even if the type is an empty class type*.